# Batch. Replace few files in a folder with another file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, readonly

First folder with path "D:\Test\1" have file "0.txt" inside.

Second folder with path "D:\Test\2" have files "1.txt", "2.txt" and "3.txt" and etc.

I want replace all .txt files in second folder with 0.txt from first folder, but i want save old names. 
When done, i want also mark all files inside second folder as "Read Only". If possible...

Very appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SET FILE0=D:\Test\1\0.txt
    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b D:\Test\2\*.txt') DO (
    xcopy %FILE0% "%%~F" /Y/R
    attrib +R "%%~F" 
    )
```

Explanation:

- `FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b D:\Test\2\*.txt')`. Loop over all files in the directory names *.txt
- `xcopy %FILE0% "%%~F" /Y/R` copy 0.txt over the existing file, supressing confirmation /Y and overwriting readonly files /R
- `attrib +R "%%~F"` Set the file to be readonly.